# wp7 - how to check if the image was loaded

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, bitmapimage

I'm trying to bind some data to a wp7 listbox (with custom item template) which includes a thumbnail image for each entry. The thing is - I'm running into one problem - when the linked image redirects to a 404 page - I get an empty image as a result and frankly - I have no idea how to check if the loaded data is a proper image or not ... here's the code I'm using right now:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Grid Height="62"
                                  Width="62">
                                <Image Stretch="UniformToFill"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center">

                                    <Image.Source>
                                        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding MiniImage}"
                                                     CreateOptions="DelayCreation, BackgroundCreation" />
                                    </Image.Source>

                                </Image>
                            </Grid>
                            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
                                           Margin="12,4,0,0"
                                           FontSize="26"
                                           FontFamily="Segoe WP Bold" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PubDate}"
                                           Margin="12,0,0,9"
                                           FontSize="16"
                                           FontStyle="Italic"
                                           Padding="5,0,0,0"
                                           FontFamily="Segoe WP"
                                           Opacity="0.5" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

and here's the code behind:

```
foreach (var item in RssFeedItems)
        {
            var inputString = item.Description;
            var tempImageList = new List<string>();
            var inputStringBuilt = new StringBuilder(item.Description);
            var temp = 1;

            while (temp > 0)
            {
                var img = inputString.IndexOf("<img", StringComparison.Ordinal);
                var src = inputString.IndexOf("src", img, StringComparison.Ordinal);
                var quot = inputString.IndexOf('"', src + 5);
                var len = quot - (src + 5);
                var sub = len > 0 ? inputString.Substring(src + 5, len) : null;
                tempImageList.Add(sub);
                var closingBracket = inputString.IndexOf(">", src, StringComparison.Ordinal);
                inputStringBuilt.Clear();
                inputStringBuilt.Append(inputString);
                inputStringBuilt.Remove(img, closingBracket - img);
                inputString = inputStringBuilt.ToString();
                temp = inputString.IndexOf("<img", StringComparison.Ordinal);
            }

            item.MiniImage = tempImageList[0] ?? "ApplicationIcon.png";

            var f = tempImageList.IndexOf(null) - 1;
            while (f >= 0)
            {
                PostImages.Add(tempImageList[f]);
                f--;
            }

            tempImageList.Clear();

            FirstListBox.Items.Add(item);

        }
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to issue a web request in your code behind, pass the results into `PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg` and bind to the `WriteableBitmap` returned from that instead of the URL.  This way you can detect error conditions in the web request and react accordingly.

Comment: hmmm ... probably a stupid question, but ... does it only work with jpgs? what about pngs? and the other thing is - how do I do this? I mean - how do I link that returned `WriteableBitmap` directly to the `BitmapImage` in my `ItemTemplate` in XAML (and not the `UriSource`)?

Comment: @lashman `<Image Source="{Binding}"/>` - `WriteableBitmap` is one of the things you can set that property to.

Comment: yeah, I know that ... the problem is - I need to use the `BitmapImage` for its `CreateOptions="DelayCreation, BackgroundCreation"` parameters ... and `BitmapImage` doesn't have `Source` ... it only has `UriSource` (directly from XAML at least)

Comment: I think you need to think more flexibly about what your problem is.  Seems to me like your choices are: 1. do everything yourself and control the flow 2. let the platform handle everything and not be informed when it fails.  Given what you asked for I think #1 outweighs whatever benefit you think #2 might be giving you.

Comment: ok, I see ... well ... if there's no other way. Thanks :) just one more question - how do I handle image loading further down the road? You know - not to block the UI thread when adding all those images to a `ListBox` ... and without using any pre-made controls (like `LazyBox` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The Image element has an event called [ImageFailed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.imagefailed%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) you will get an exception (contained in the ExceptionRoutedEventArgs)

You could use this to detect error when loading images.